# Scrollview hiding the bottom textview

Tags: android-layout, textview, android-scrollview, android

I've been having headache for this whole scrollview/textview thing for couple days. I have a Scrollview containing a textview, then I have another textview (status) beneath it.

1. the scroll/text, once containing a long result text, will drop down to the bottom of my screen and completely hide my "status" textview, which is supposed to be always 1 line at the bottom of my screen.
2. the i want to have gravity so that as the result text becomes longer, the scrollbar automatically scrolls to the bottom when I have new lines. I have tried adding a gravity = bottom to the "textResult" textview, but it doesn't work - the scrollbar won't move even when I'm having new lines (that goes beyond the bottom of the screen) in the text result.

-How could I solve this please? Thanks so much!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollResult"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textResult"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            />
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:editable="false"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollResult"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:maxHeight="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This it may be help to you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollResult"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/status"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textResult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:editable="false"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:maxHeight="20dp"

    android:maxLines="1"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```